# My Discord bot does not respond to my messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a bot using Python. I am very new to coding with Python and I don't understand a lot of things, I am just following a tutorial(https://youtu.be/j_sD9udZnCk) but I am stuck with my bot not responding to my messages. It goes online and offline as intented but it does not respond to my messages. Also it is an administrator in my Discord server. This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () =>{ 
    console.log('Money Farmer is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args =  message.content.slice(prefix.length).split("");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.sendMessage('pong!');
    }
});


client.login('My token');
```

Comment: This is NodeJS and not Python

Comment: Try to `console.log()` args and the command and let us know what the output is please

Comment: I added console.log(args); and nothing happened, the bot didn'e respond

Comment: Is the bot running? Is there a "Money Farmer is online!'" in the console? If yes, the problem is in the first line after the messageEvent (client.on('message'....)

Comment: the "money farmer is online!" message pops up in the console and the bot goes online. It just doesn't respond to the message "-ping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code to fix your problem:

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
const command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(prefix.length).toLowerCase();
```

First you [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the the message and then you [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the first element for your args variable.
To get the command you split the `message.content` and take the first element of the Array. Then you slice the prefix from the Array and `toLowerCase()` the command.

Comment: YOU DID! YOU CRAZY MAN, YOU DID IT. You actually fixed it. I know it was probably a simple fix, but I couldn't find anyone online with the same problem. Thanks again!